# Meteor: register form sometimes doesn’t render properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, meteor

some users (including me) don’t see the register form at all - especially in chrome.

Please have a look in Firefox first:
http://openstrategynetwork.com/joinus

What happens in Chrome:

[image]

The buttons and input fields only start appearing when you hover over the the area:

[image]
[image]

Or everything appears when the browser window is resized.

The oddest - and a bit spooky - thing is when I scroll back up, I see the register form in the background:

[image]

I’m using the `useraccounts` package.

**Note**: Here’s the [all source](https://github.com/OpenStratNet/OSN).

My config file (config/at_config.js):

```
// Options
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  // preSignUpHook: function (error, state) {
  //   console.log("love");
  // },
  // defaultLayout: 'emptyLayout',
  focusFirstInput: false,
  showForgotPasswordLink: true,
  overrideLoginErrors: true,
  enablePasswordChange: true,

  sendVerificationEmail: true,
  // enforceEmailVerification: true,
  //confirmPassword: true,
  //continuousValidation: false,
  showLabels: false,
  //forbidClientAccountCreation: true,
  //formValidationFeedback: true,
  homeRoutePath: '/',
  redirectTimeout: 2000,
  //showAddRemoveServices: false,
  showPlaceholders: true,

  negativeValidation: true,
  positiveValidation: true,
  negativeFeedback: true,
  positiveFeedback: true,

  // Privacy Policy and Terms of Use
  //privacyUrl: 'privacy',
  //termsUrl: 'terms-of-use',
  texts: {
    sep: "OR REGISTER with your social account:",
    title: {
      signUp: "REGISTER by creating a new account:"
    },
    button: {
      signUp: "REGISTER"
    },
    socialSignUp: "",
    socialWith: ""
  }
});

var submitFunction = function(error, state){
  // if (!error) {
  //   if (state === "signIn") {
  //     // Successfully logged in
  //     console.log("hook logged in");
  //   }
  //   if (state === "signUp") {
  //     // Successfully registered
  //     console.log("hook singup");
  //   }
  // }
};


// remove fields and add them back in the right order
AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');
AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');


//all register fields
AccountsTemplates.addFields([
    {
      _id: 'firstName',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "First Name*",
      required: true,
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter your first name.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'lastName',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Last Name*",
      required: true,
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter your last name.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: "Email Address*",
      required: true,
      displayName: "email",
      re: /.+@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/,
      errStr: 'Invalid email',
    },
    {
      _id: 'institution',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Institution/Company*",
      required: true,
      // re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      minLength: 2,
      errStr: "Please enter the institution or company you work for.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'interests',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Interests regarding Open Strategy*",
      required: true,
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter the your interests in the institution/company.",
      template: 'interests'
    },
    {
      _id: 'position',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: "Position",
      re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
      errStr: "Please enter the your position in the institution/company.",
    },
    {
      _id: 'uploadProfile',
      type: 'text',
      template: 'uploadInput'
    },
    {
      _id: 'password',
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: "Password*",
      required: true,
      minLength: 6,
      errStr: 'Password must be at least six characters long',
    },
    {
      _id: 'password_again',
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: "Confirm Password*",
      required: true,
      minLength: 6,
      errStr: 'Password must be at least six characters long',
    }
]);
```

My helpers file (client/templates/account-templates/joinus.js):

```
Template.joinUs.onRendered(function () {
  // if scrolling is necessary $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  // SCRIPT
    setInterval(function(){
        if(window.location.href.split('/').pop()=='joinus'){
            var pswVal = $("[name='at-field-password']")[0].value;
            var pswValL = pswVal.length;
            var pswAVal = $("[name='at-field-password_again']")[0].value;
            var pswAValL = pswAVal.length;
            if(pswVal==pswAVal && pswValL>5 && pswAValL>5){
                $('.form-group:eq(15) .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove.form-control-feedback').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok').css("color","green");
                $('.form-group:eq(15) .help-block').addClass('hide');
                $("[name='at-field-password_again']").css({"border-style":"solid", "border-color":"green"})
            }else{
                $("[name='at-field-password_again']").css({"border-style":"", "border-color":""});
                $('.form-group:eq(15) .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove.form-control-feedback').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').css("color","");
                $('.form-group:eq(15) .help-block').removeClass('hide');
            }
        }   
    }, 10);
});

Template.joinUs.events({
  'click .js-scrollToForm': function (evt, tpl) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#js-scrollStop').offset().top - 35
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

My html file (client/templates/account-templates/joinus.html):

```
<template name="joinUs">

  <!-- Stage -->
  <header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <!-- Breadcrumb -->
        <ol class="breadcrumb text-left">
            <li><a class="breadcrumb-link" href="{{pathFor route = 'home'}}">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Join us</li>
        </ol><!-- End of Breadcrumb -->
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <h1>YOUR BENEFITS</h1>
            <hr>
            <h2>As a member of OSN you will become part of a thriving network of scholars interested in open strategy. There are many advantages of joining the OSN. Registration is free.</h2>
            <button type="button" href="#joinus" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll js-scrollToForm">JOIN US</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header> <!-- ./Stage -->

  <!-- Services Section -->
  <section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center extra-spacing-top extra-spacing-bottom joinus-icons">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i> -->
                    <i class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">News</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">As a member you can submit news to the whole Open Strategy community and disseminate related research findings.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i> -->
                    <i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse joinus-icons"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Collaborations</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Collaborate internationally by searching for data on OSN members.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i> -->
                    <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Literature</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Search for Open Strategy literature on specific topics within the Bibliography</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- <div id="js-scrollStop"></div> -->

  <!--     Registration Form -->
  <section class="bg-light-gray extra-spacing-top" id="js-scrollStop">
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            {{> atForm state='signUp'}}
        </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Jeremy Iglehart the error might be boiled down to this file:

client/templates/account-templates/at_form_mod.html:

```
<template name="myAtForm">
  {{#unless hide}}
    <div class="at-form">
      <!-- {{#if showTitle}}
        {{> atTitle}}
      {{/if}} -->
      {{#if showError}}
        {{> atError}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showResult}}
        {{> atResult}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showPwdForm}}
        {{> atPwdForm}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showTermsLink}}
        {{> atTermsLink}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showSignUpLink}}
        {{> atSignupLink}}
      {{/if}}
      <!-- {{#if showServicesSeparator}}
        {{> atSep}}
      {{/if}} -->
      {{#if showOauthServices}}
        {{> atOauth}}
      {{/if}}
      <!-- {{#if showSignInLink}}
        {{> atSigninLink}}
      {{/if}} -->
    </div> <!-- end main div -->
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

The .less file can be found here (too long to paste in here):
client/templates/styles/styles.less

Comment: Amir, First off - great design... keep it up, you'll get there.  This to me feels like a rogue CSS problem no?  Something is being set to hidden or something.  Do you have any CSS in there which might be doing this?

Comment: It looks to me like https://github.com/OpenStratNet/OSN/blob/master/client/templates/account-templates/at_form_mod.html is where your problem might be - the `{{#unless hide}} and below that where you have the {{#if `showOauthServices}}` where do you define `hide` and `showOauthServices`?

Comment: @JeremyIglehart: Thanks for your motivational words. Very kind of you :) Although I was thinking to stop programming after this project :(  Unfortunately, I don't know where this is defined. It's in the useraccounts package. But it's a already a good hint. Thanks a lot :) Amir P.S.: I just wonder why Chrome has issues

Comment: Never give up! Don't let them win like that ;P  You can do this, just keep it up and be consistent.  Eventually you will crack this nut or find a way around it.  And after that some time in the future you will have a harder problem, and you will solve that one too.  Keep it up.  This is what we do, and you can do it too!  Great design, you're doing very well.  Enjoy the problems, enjoy getting stuck, and enjoy the feeling when you solve it too.  The longer the night, the brighter the dawn.

Answer (score 1):

Amir, I don't know why Chrome is the one giving you issues.

If I were you, I'd edit this.  Unless you really need that "hide" I would just take out all of those if statements.  It looks to me like your design wants that page to be up all the time.

Take out what you don't want from the template level and see what you got.

This is a hack, but it might get you moving.

For example:

```
<template name="myAtForm">
    <div class="at-form">
        {{> atTitle}}
      {{#if showError}}
        {{> atError}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showResult}}
        {{> atResult}}
      {{/if}}

        {{> atPwdForm}}

      {{#if showTermsLink}}
        {{> atTermsLink}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showSignUpLink}}
        {{> atSignupLink}}
      {{/if}}
      <!-- {{#if showServicesSeparator}}
        {{> atSep}}
      {{/if}} -->
        {{> atOauth}}
      <!-- {{#if showSignInLink}}
        {{> atSigninLink}}
      {{/if}} -->
    </div> <!-- end main div -->
</template>
```

Just take out what you don't need there.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, don't give up! You'll find it.  I think the best thing for you is to study [this meteorchef link](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/roll-your-own-authentication/) and "roll your own".  I bet if you read through [this whole article](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/roll-your-own-authentication/) you'll figure out what you need to do.

Comment: Don't be sorry. Thanks for your warm words.